# std::move realisation

Tags: c++, std, c++11, move-constructor

I got next snippet from [microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx)

```
template <typename T> struct RemoveReference {
     typedef T type;
};

template <typename T> struct RemoveReference<T&> {
     typedef T type;
};

template <typename T> struct RemoveReference<T&&> {
     typedef T type;
};

template <typename T> typename RemoveReference<T>::type&& Move(T&& t) {
    return t;
}
```

...

```
remote_integer x = frumple(5);
remote_integer&& x1 = Move(x);
```

and i get an error "error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'remote_integer' to 'remote_integer &&'"

something changed in compilers? With std::move all goes right.

Comment: Move only accepts a rvalue, x is an lvalue. You must use stdmove (lowercase) for it.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vs2010ctpcpp/thread/ab120b3c-4ecf-4a0d-8f64-f24925ac39a9/ - Jonathan Caves (Visual C++ Compiler Team) write realisation of std::move the same with my Move. And Move i grabbed from microsoft site, link in the question post? and there all right, but in VC10 it doesnt work.

Comment: template <typename T> typename RemoveReference<T>::type&& Move(T&& t) {
    return (RemoveReference<T>::type&&)t;
} - now all works fine, something with type casting here.

Comment: Now i understand your problem, you copied it out of the site. You should use the std::move provided under the utilities header tho. It's implementation is (just like your fix) `// TEMPLATE FUNCTION move template<class _Ty> inline typename tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&& move(_Ty&& _Arg) { return ((typename tr1::_Remove_reference<_Ty>::_Type&&)_Arg); }`

Comment: Yes, i did it after keek into utility module realisation))) Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to write your own implementation of `std::move`?

Comment: @Red: Move accepts an lvalue and converts it to an xvalue. There is no point in passing an rvalue to `move` since an rvalue will bind to an rvalue reference without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your `Move` doesn't work, is because `t` is always **lvalue** (even when `T&&` resolves to, say, `int&&`). Even though it might seem weird, named rvalue references are indeed lvalues.

When returning from your `Move`, you attempt to implicitly bind lvalue to rvalue reference, which is forbidden by standard (§8.5.3). As noted in the comments, you have to cast `t` explicitly to rvalue reference.

Relevant parts of standard are §5/4 and §5/5, but I'm going to quote note §5/6, which sums this nicely:

> In general, the effect of this rule is that named rvalue references
>   are treated as lvalues and unnamed rvalue references to objects are
>   treated as xvalues; rvalue references to functions are treated as
>   lvalues whether named or not.

Correct implementation is indeed:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& t)
{
  return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t);
}
```

---

As far as I remember, this code used to be valid in earlier drafts. But since the rules have changed, you have to provide explicit cast now (same applies to std::forward).